# set frame for tableview section index in swift programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search

Is it possible to set frame for section indexes of tableview. Because section index is overlapping my Search bar.[image]

This indexed view background color should be white color but it wouldn't overlap the search bar. Please help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Can you give try to this:

```
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSectionIndexColor:)]) {
    tableView.sectionIndexColor = ... // some clear color
   tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = ... // some clear color
    tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = ... // some clear other color
}
```

Alternatively, you can also displace your searchBar from '**headerview**' to '**subview**' by the following:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
.......

self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;

[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];

..........
```

In addition to that, it is best practice to return the sorted keys in 
'sectionIndexTitlesForTableView' delegate and which will reduce the indexes count and the height will get reduced in most cases.